# Autocreate tables in Bigquery for multiple CSV files

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I want to generate tables automatically in Bigquery whenever a file is uploaded in storage bucket using cloud function in python.

For example- if sample1.csv file is uploaded to bucket then a sample1 table will be created in Bigquery.
How to automate it using cloud function using Python i tried with below code but was able to generate 1 table and all data got appended to that table, how to proceed

```
def hello_gcs(event, context):
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client()

    # TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
    table_id = "test_project.test_dataset.test_Table"

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    autodetect=True,
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
    )
    uri = "gs://test_bucket/*.csv"

    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  # Make an API request.

    load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

    destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
    print("Processing file: {file['name']}.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to do three things:

1. Extract the name of the CSV file/object from the notification event you're receiving to fire your function.
2. Update the `table_id` in your example code to set the table name based on the filename you extracted in the first step.
3. Update the `uri` in your example code to only use the single file as the input.  As written, your example attempts to load data from *all* matching CSV objects in GCS to the table.

Comment: @Daemon could you please share you are loading in uri only single file as output.Like this:  # TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
    table_id = event['name']

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    autodetect=True,
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
    )
    uri = "gs://test_bucket/event['name'].csv"